# Какой наиболее эффективный способ рендера в браузере jpeg-изображений blob?

Tags: javascript, html5, jpeg, render, blob

Через вебсокеты в браузер приходят сырые jpeg-кадры (20-25 штук в секунду). Они принимаются в arraybuffer из которого расчитывается base64 и вставляется в img.src. На странице должно отображаться до 20 таких видеопотоков, и мне кажется неэффективным такой метод вывода изображений.

Как быстрее всего рендерить blob jpeg-изображения в браузере с минимально возможными издержками на вычисления и как следствие загрузкой процессора?

Comment: Object.createObjecturl()

Comment: А примерно, насколько это быстрее base64?

Comment: По идее на одно копирование.

Comment: @zb', сделал `CamSocket.onmessage = function(event){Stream.src =URL.createObjectURL(event.data);  setTimeout(function({CamSocket.send(Request);},40);};` - а как его обновлять? Загружает только первый кадр и всё. Пробовал в img.onload делать revoke url this.src - не помогает.

Comment: Так а просто смена src разве не работает? Revoke, это чтобы конкретный буфер убить

Comment: Есть ещё mediasource api, но оно какое то странное. Еще можно в канвас рисовать